# jQuery pre -loader ie-6/7 issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, preloader

I got this jQuery pre-loading script running on a index.html page loading about 10Mb before redirecting to a other page.

It works fine in IE8/9 FF3+ and Chrome.
But it does not seem to work in IE6/7, it seems to start and run but never fires the last part.

Working example: -removed-

Anyone knows why it gets stuck on 75/76 files loaded in ie6/7?

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($) {
var imgList = [];
$.extend({
    preload: function(imgArr, option) {
        var setting = $.extend({
            init: function(loaded, total) {},
            loaded: function(img, loaded, total) {},
            loaded_all: function(loaded, total) {}
        }, option);
        var total = imgArr.length;
        var loaded = 0;

        setting.init(0, total);
        for (i = 0; i < imgArr.length; i++) {
            imgList.push($("<img />")
                .load(function() {
                    loaded++;
                    setting.loaded(this, loaded, total);
                    if(loaded == total) {
                        setting.loaded_all(loaded, total);
                    }
                })
                .attr("src", imgArr[i])
            );
        }
    }
});
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
$.preload([
"http://www.erikderuiter.nl/images/300x300-transparent.png",
"http://www.erikderuiter.nl/images/300x300.png",
"http://www.erikderuiter.nl/images/300x600.png",
"http://www.erikderuiter.nl/images/600x300.png",
"http://www.erikderuiter.nl/images/600x600.png",
"http://www.erikderuiter.nl/images/900x300.png",
], {
    init: function(loaded, total) {
        $("#indicator").html("Files: "+loaded+"/"+total);
    },
    loaded: function(img, loaded, total) {
        $("#indicator").html("Files: "+loaded+"/"+total);
        $("#full-screen").append(img);
    },
    loaded_all: function(loaded, total) {
        $("#indicator").html("Loading: Done!");
        window.location.replace("http://www.erikderuiter.nl/somepage.html");
    }
});
});
</script>

<div id="indicator"></div>
```

Any other tips or best practices to preload images on a page are welcome as well of course.

Comment: You have an extra comma in your array, I'm assuming that's a typo just in question since IE8 would have failed on that.

Comment: Yes, the array was way longer. shortened it for this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also test if the image is already cached.

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = "foo.jpg";
if (img.complete || img.readyState === 4) {
    // image is cached
}
else {
    $(img).bind("load error onreadystatechange",function(e){
        // image is loaded
    });
}
```

If there is a 404 error on one of the images, you will need to catch that with a `setTimeout` and `clearTimeout`.

Edit: Just a note before i get bombarded for using `.bind`: I still use `.bind` in plugins for backwards compatibility.

Here's an example of the above method: https://github.com/tentonaxe/jQuery-preloadImages/blob/master/jquery.preloadimages.js

Edit again: After reading this over again, I'm not sure if caching is the problem you are having at the moment. It's definitely something that may come up later if you don't check for it, but it may not be related to the problem you are having.

Comment: Even when I clear the whole browser so there is no cache ie6/7 still fail.
All images in the array exist and are able to be loaded in other browsers. Ill look into your example. Hope i can use it.

Comment: Here's your code in a jsfiddle for testing, loading 100 graphics from photobucket. http://jsfiddle.net/NJZvz/ It seems to be working in IE7, it just takes a moment to finish with the last one.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i'am not familiar with json or yahooapis.

Comment: It's just an alternative to a static array of images, shouldn't make any difference as that's just the list of images we are preloading. What i'm saying is your plugin is working for me in IE7 8 and 9.